# count distinct is returning a different number of items than adding the column with group by

Tags: sql

I am attempting to get an accurate count. When I add the column and select group by, it returns 1,749 rows. When I instead `count(distinct table1_pidm)`, it returns 1793. Below is my redacted code with count(distinct table1). When I replace line 2 with `table1_PIDM "Pidm"`, there are 1749 rows. What is causing the difference here? My understanding is that count doesn't count null values. Distinct should prevent duplicate values.

If it is the count that is correct, why is it not displaying that number of Pidms? If count is incorrect, how do I change the code to make the count correct?

If the syntax is at all funky, it's because it's an Argos report. Argos Mapplet 6.9.1.2083 / Argos Client 6.9.1.2477

I tried both:

code set 1

```
select distinct Sum( table1_GRS  ) "GrossWages",
       Count(distinct table1_PIDM) "Count_unique_PIDMs"
  from table1 table1,
       table2 table2
 where ( table1_EARN_CODE = table2_CODE )
   and ( ( table1_YEAR =:PayYear )
         and ( table1_MONTH >=:QtrBeg
           and table1_MONTH <=:QtrEnd )
         and ( table1_EARN_CODE NOT IN ('list of data') )
         and ( table2_CASH_IND <> 'N' ) )
having Sum(table1_GRS) > 0
```

And code set 2

```
select distinct Sum( table1_GRS  ) "GrossWages",
       table1_PIDM "Pidm"
  from table1 table1,
       table2 table2
 where ( table1_EARN_CODE = table2_CODE )
   and ( ( table1_YEAR =:PayYear )
         and ( table1_MONTH >=:QtrBeg
           and table1_MONTH <=:QtrEnd )
         and ( table1_EARN_CODE NOT IN ('list of data') )
         and ( table2_CASH_IND <> 'N' ) )
having Sum(table1_GRS) > 0
```

I expected the count in code set 1 to equal the number of rows in code set 2.

Comment: A [mcve] would make things much clearer here. We don't know your tables or data.

Comment: Anyway, your second query is invalid and expected to raise an error. Which dbms are you using?